# LNK2019 error trying to compile project using tmxlite

Tags: c++, tiled, tmx

I keep getting these errors:

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _mz_inflateInit referenced in function "bool __cdecl tmx::decompress(char const *,class std::vector &,int,int)" (?decompress@tmx@@YA_NPBDAAV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@hh@Z)

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _mz_inflate referenced in function "bool __cdecl tmx::decompress(char const *,class std::vector > &,int,int)" (?decompress@tmx@@YA_NPBDAAV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@HH@Z)

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _mz_inflateEnd referenced in function "bool __cdecl tmx::decompress(char const *,class std::vector > &,int,int)" (?decompress@tmx@@YA_NPBDAAV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@HH@Z)

when I try to compiler my tmxlite project. The only source code files I have in my project are the ones that came with tmxlite.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Event.hpp>

#include <tmxlite/Map.hpp> 

#include "C:\Program Files (x86)\tmxlite\SFMLExample\src\SFMLOrthogonalLayer.hpp"

#include "FreeFuncs.cpp"
#include "ImageLayer.cpp"
#include "Map.cpp"
#include "miniz.c"
#include "Object.cpp"
#include "ObjectGroup.cpp"
#include "Property.cpp"
#include "TileLayer.cpp"
#include "Tileset.cpp"
#include "pugixml.cpp"

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
        RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

        tmx::Map map;
        map.load("assets/demo.tmx");

        MapLayer layerZero(map, 0);
        MapLayer layerOne(map, 1);
        MapLayer layerTwo(map, 2);

        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }

            window.clear(Color::Black);
            window.draw(layerZero);
            window.draw(layerOne);
            window.draw(layerTwo);
            window.display();
        }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017

Comment: What are you including cpp files?

Answer (score 0):

Add existing `src/tmxlite/miniz.*` files into you project. Including `Map.*` only into your project is not enough, you should add all source files into the project.

The better way is if you add the existing project `tmxlite.vcxproj` into your solution and add this project into the dependencies of your project.

Do not include .cpp files into your sources using `#include` directive. Add them into your project tree.

Comment: Sorry I should have included that with my code here. I have included miniz.h. I still get the same errors.

Comment: No `#include`. Right click on you project in the project view and add existing fires into the project, both .h and .c files. Remove all `#include` of .cpp from your source.

Comment: So right-click on my project and add all files from src (not the CMakeLists) and src/detail? Do I need the .hpp files or just the .cpp file?

Comment: Both header and source files. Do not forget to add .c files too.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but it's not working. It gives me hundreds of errors now.

Comment: Is it because you did not remove `#include "FreeFuncs.cpp"` and other included .cpp fires?

Comment: No I removed those. According to another source, I need to build the library to get the .lib files first which I don't know how to do. It comes with a sln file but when I open that in VS and say 'build' it does nothing.